# Python Package Installation Issue: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pip, modulenotfounderror, pipfile

I'm trying to use [modal-python](https://pypi.org/project/modAL-python/) package.

When using a Google Colab notebook, after I install the package `pip install modal-python` I can easily use the package as expected. eg: `from modAL.models import ActiveLearner`.

But When I'm working on my mac, altough my pipfile contains the dependencies as mentioned in the [installation page](https://modal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/overview/Installation.html):

```
numpy >= "1.13"
scipy >= "0.18"
scikit-learn >= "0.18"
modal-python = "*"
```

after installing the dependecies `pipenv install` and running the enviroment `pipenv shell` (Despite getting *Requirement already satisfied* and Piplock file generated)
I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modAl'` while running the exact code snippet that works in Google Colab notebook.

How should I find the root of the issue?

The complete trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/m/active/hello.py", line 2, in <module>
    from modAl.models import ActiveLearner
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modAl'
```

When I run `pip list` all the dependencies are installed:

```
numpy                         1.26.3
scipy                         1.11.4
scikit-learn                  1.3.2
modAL-python                  0.4.2.1
```

Comment: Run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and compare the dependencies

Comment: And try to install it separately. `pip install modal-python`

Comment: You probably have multiple, confused Python distributions installed. Try `print(sys.executable)` and `print(sys.path)` before importing modal-python to see which Python you are using and where it is looking for packages. Then outside your IDE try `pip show modal-python` to see where `pip` has actually installed it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a Pipenv, you will have to use:

```
pipenv run python hello.py
```

You cannot just run it normally unless you interpreter is set to the environment. If it doesn't work, activate the environment and then try again.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to install the modal-python package separately. `pip install modal-python`

Comment: Yes, I have already tried installing it separately. Still the error exists.